# Jsdom how to "poll for the presence of a specific element."?

Tags: typescript, jsdom

In the jsdom docs https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom, under Asynchronous script loading, polling for the presence of a specific element is recommended as a method for making sure the dom loads what you need.

The below code is my interpretation of doing that:

```
const elementOnPage = (arg: HTMLElement | null): HTMLElement => {
  let tried = arg;
  while (tried === null) {
    // debugger;
    console.log("nothing yet");
    tried = arg;
  }
  return tried;
};
```

then call the function like so:

```
...
await elementOnPage(
        dom.window.document.querySelector("#some element that I know will eventually be loaded onto the page")
      );
...
```

Despite the fact that I know this element will be loaded eventually, this causes an infinite loop. It seems like the argument may be evaluated to null the first time,then set to null each subsequent time, but I am not sure. In any case, I also tried using

```
dom.window.document.getElementsByClassName("some class that will eventually have member elements")
```

and checking that resulting collection length is not 0, but this returns the same infinite loop. I don't think the dom selector method is the problem. So, what is causing this infinite loop, and/or is there a better way to poll for an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple misunderstandings here:

1. The call to `elementOnPage(querySelector(...))` is executed *once* (unless that code itself is in some loop or event handler). If the DOM element exists at the time of execution it returns immediately, otherwise it will never execute the selector again so your function will run endlessly with `null` as the argument it was given.
2. In JavaScript, loops like `while` are blocking (not including workers which are unrelated here), so you are basically locking up the thread. Even if you were re-running the `querySelector` from inside the loop it would result in an infinite loop.

To perform polling without blocking JS execution you want to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Also, an awaitable function should return a `Promise` (technically you can `await` anything, but a promise is your means to make it useful).

Here's an untested example:

```
const elementOnPage = (query: string, timeout: number = 10000): Promise<HTMLElement | null> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const startTime = Date.now();
    const tryQuery = () => {
      const elem = dom.window.document.querySelector(query);
      if (elem) resolve(elem); // Found the element
      else if (Date.now() - startTime > timeout) resolve(null); // Give up eventually
      else setTimeout(tryQuery, 10); // check again every 10ms
    }
    tryQuery(); // Initial check
  });
};


// Elsewhere:
const elem = await elementOnPage("#some_element");
```

Comment: I see. Makes sense because I tried to pass a promise that returns the queryselector instead of the selector itself, but it still seemed to return an infinite loop. So how would I determine the interval to use? Just arbitrarily? Suppose I used an interval of 2 seconds. This should be long enough for the scripts on a page to load, but suppose on a very slow connection it isn't?

Comment: I added an example. You could make the interval to check very small, like every 10ms or even 1ms (though actual execution will not be that precise). As long as you do it in an interval.